# Why does a vertical scroll bar appear when I edit a datatable in bokeh?

Tags: python, dataframe, datatable, scrollbar, bokeh

I have a datatable

`DataTable(columns=columns, editable=True, selectable=True, autosize_mode='fit_columns', visible=False, height_policy='fit', index_position=None, width=60, margin=(5,5,5,0))`.

Even when it only has a few rows and everything is visible, when I try to edit the (only) column, a horizontal and vertical scroll bar appear. How can I get read of both of them, especially the vertical one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably cheated, but when I put non-editable columns next to the editable column then no scroll bars appear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).